# NASM assembly reading file - detecting EOF

Tags: assembly, nasm, readfile

I have trouble exiting loop while reading a file byte after byte. In loop I compare read byte with EOF ( = -1). Previously I was putting read byte into register so I could see it in dbg and it turns out that program hangs on last byte from the file.

```
SYS_READ    equ 0
SYS_OPEN    equ 2
SYS_EXIT    equ 60
O_RDONLY    equ 0
EOF         equ -1

section .data
    filename db "test3.txt",0

section .bss
    number resb 1
    fd resb 8 

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    call _read_file
    call _sys_exit_0

_read_file:
    call _sys_open
    mov [fd], rax
_read_file_loop:    
    call _sys_read
    cmp byte [number], EOF
    jne _read_file_loop
    ret

_sys_open:
    mov rax, SYS_OPEN
    mov rdi, filename
    mov rsi, O_RDONLY
    mov rdx, 0644o
    syscall
    ret

_sys_read:
    mov rax, SYS_READ
    mov rdi, [fd]
    mov rsi, number
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    ret

_sys_exit_0:
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Comment: `EOF` is returned in `rax` not in `number`. Also, it's zero not -1.

Comment: `EOF = -1 = 255` is `fgetc` "feature", when you use `read` syscall, just check returned value which is the number of bytes read. If 0 bytes are read that means file has ended.